# Algorithm to find best combination of departments

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, linear-programming

Assume I have a set of departments in say a hospital, each department has it's own running cost. Additionally, some departments can be combined which will result in a running cost lower then the individual costs of those two departments. Note that not every combination of two departments can be merged.

Example data:

```
+------------+------+
| Department | Cost |
+------------+------+
| 1          |5     |
| 2          |3     |
| 3          |4     | 
| 4          |5     |
| 1,2        |6     | 
| 3,4        |7     |
+------------+------+
```

I would like to minimize the total cost, is there a standard linear program or algorithm to solve this? I am currently working in python but anything can help.

Comment: Sounds like a minimum weight exact cover problem to me; it should be an NP hard problem, but a quick search doesn't find much about the weighted version of the problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover

Comment: If the options of which departments can be merged only include pairs of departments - i.e. there are no sets of 3 or more departments which can be merged - then it can be reduced to the maximum weight matching problem, by assigning each pair with the "cost saving" associated with merging that pair and maximising the cost saving. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching This problem is solvable in polynomial time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm

Comment: @kaya3, Thank you! The exact cover problem will work for me.